# RavendDB faceted search results formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, formatting, ravendb, faceted-search

Currently I'm playing with faceted search after reading [RavenDB doc](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/faceted-search) about it.

The result returned is OK, but there's a small problem. Since the result comes as

```
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<FacetValue>>
```

it's necessary to iterate over it and do some fancy string manipulation to format the result and show it in a PartialView. More specifically this facet:

```
new Facet
    {
        Name = "Value_Range",
        Mode = FacetMode.Ranges,
        Ranges =
            {
                "[NULL TO Dx500.0]",
                "[Dx500.0 TO Dx1000.0]",
                "[Dx1000.0 TO Dx2500.0]",
                "[Dx2500.0 TO Dx5000.0]",
                "[Dx5000.0 TO NULL]",
            }
    }
```

`View` code:

```
@fv.Range
```

This is this "**beautiful**" string that gets output on the view: `[Dx400.0 TO Dx600.0]`

RavenDB uses the Dx prefix above to do a [number to string conversion](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Abstractions/Indexing/NumberUtil.cs#L43).

`Controller` code where the facet result is passed to a specific `ViewModel`:

```
var facetResults = DocumentSession.Query<Realty>("RealtyFacets")
            //.Where(x => x.Value >= 100 && x.Value <= 1000)
            .ToFacets("facets/RealtyFacets").ToArray();

var model = new RealtyFacetsViewModel();

model.Cities = facetResults[0];
model.Purposes = facetResults[1];
model.Types = facetResults[2];
model.Values = facetResults[3];

return PartialView("RealtyFacets", model);
```

Is there any other/better way of getting results from a faceted search so that no string manipulation must be done to format the returned data?

After Ayende's suggestion, I did this in my controller:

```
foreach (var val in facetResults[3].Value)
{
    switch(val.Range)
    {
        case "[Dx0.0 TO Dx200.0]":
            val.Range = string.Format("{0:C2} {1} {2:C2}",
                                        0, @Localization.to, 200);
            break;
        case "[Dx200.0 TO Dx400.0]":
            val.Range = string.Format("{0:C2} {1} {2:C2}",
                                        200, @Localization.to, 400);
            break;
        case "[Dx400.0 TO Dx600.0]":
            val.Range = string.Format("{0:C2} {1} {2:C2}",
                                        400, @Localization.to, 600);
            break;
        case "[Dx600.0 TO Dx800.0]":
            val.Range = string.Format("{0:C2} {1} {2:C2}",
                                        600, @Localization.to, 800);
            break;
        case "[Dx800.0 TO Dx1000000.0]":
            val.Range = string.Format("{0:C2} {1} {2:C2}",
                                        800, @Localization.to, 1000000);
            break;
    }
}

model.Values = facetResults[3];
```

Comment: @ Just to add to Oren's answer, I implemented the facet API like that because it was easier ;-) Plus making the developer write the exact Lucene query for each facet allows more flexibility. Otherwise the API would have to know all the possible grouping scenarios that you'd want to use. But as a results the API doesn't really know what your grouping is, it's just executes the lucene query you give it.

Comment: You could however make you code a bit simpler, by using more generic code that converts "Dx800.0" -> 800.0. See here for how RavenDB does it internally, https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Abstractions/Indexing/NumberUtil.cs

Comment: In fact even better just call the NumberUtils.StringToNumber(..) and have RavenDB convert it for you. The code is in Raven.Abstractions which you can access in the Client API.

Comment: @MattWarren: awesome job on the Facet API my friend. Keep it evolving... I used your advice. See my answer bellow. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah that's spot on. Also you can use the other methods in that class to do the reverse, i.e. generate the range string from given numbers. That way it makes constructing the facet setup doc a bit easier.

Comment: Yeah Matt, it can even be configurable let's say in the Web.config. It's just a matter of pulling those numbers out and use them while constructing the facets. Fantastic! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [@MattWarren suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414077/ravenddb-faceted-search-results-formatting/9434424#comment11921270_9414077), I ended up using:

```
foreach (var val in facetResults[3].Value)
{
    // Original string format: [Dx5000.0 TO Dx10000.0]
    var limits = val.Range.Split(new string[] { "TO", "[", "]", " " },
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // Leveraging RavenDB NumberUtil class...
    val.Range = string.Format("{0:C0} {1} {2:C0}",
    Raven.Abstractions.Indexing.NumberUtil.StringToNumber(limits.ElementAt(0)),
    @Localization.to,
    Raven.Abstractions.Indexing.NumberUtil.StringToNumber(limits.ElementAt(1)));      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Leniel,
In your code, create a dictionary that would map between the facet value and the display string.
RavenDB currently have no way to influence the facet value.

Comment: OK. I get the idea. Since I haven't seen a sample of this at work in the View side I thought there would be a way of getting it right from RavenDB itself...